# Passing command line arguments to mono-service

Tags: c#, mono, command-line-arguments, mono-service

Is there a way to pass command line arguments to a service invoked by mono-service? All of the command line arguments seem to be absorbed by mono-service instead of passed to the service.

Comment: are you using an Assembly with a Main method? [You should already be able to 'catch' the command line arguments from there](https://github.com/sehe/mono/commit/64ecfe59e7cffb1bbef54be2e9fc32bdc755fd12#commitcomment-626702), but see [my post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636395/passing-command-line-arguments-to-mono-service/7636498#7636498) for a possible patch if it really wasn't by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Update: as per my patch that went in end 2011 you can now use the intended interface of `mono-service`.

---

[AFAICT there is no way](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mono-service).

The idiomatic way to do things would be to use an app.config file to contain [Configuration Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) (in XML).

**Update**

That seems odd. The `assebmblyArgs` [*sic*] are being passed as part of the `activationAttributes` to [`AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap Method (String, String, Boolean, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo, Object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd414842.aspx), but being ignored in the call to `OnStart`.

You could try compiling a modified version of `mono-service.exe` using the following source:

#### * see [github gist](http://gist.github.com/9e1c6397c0f049fd8470/38636027d6462587458094d25523ace75f513473) or [commit for review](https://github.com/sehe/mono/commit/4273a6e14f723301e7c9e7cedaece45e1b156864)

Compile to `mono-service.exe` with `-r:System.ServiceProcess.dll -r:Mono.Posix.dll -unsafe`

---

#### OLDER STUFF:

<sub>**Update 1** Strike that. Judging from **[the code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/mono-service/mono-service.cs#L53)** you should just be able to pass options trailing the assembly name.</sub>

This implies that the following should do what you expect:

```
 mono-service -l:/root/service-lock MyService.exe /Param1 /Param2 bla.txt
```

Comment: I don't think they're passed to `OnStart`, but rather into `Main`. Let me test and I'll let you know.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer: FYI the patch has been applied to [Mono github](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/1bedeb9b324f20c6b91276b4f49e2407c9eba194) today by Miguel himself :) This means that you can expect things to work better with params passed to `mono-service` in the future

Comment: Although it does not seem to be documented anywhere, you can meanwhile use `mono-service service.exe /arg1 /arg2`, with `{"/arg1", "/arg2"}` being passed to `string[] args` of `OnStart`.

Comment: @chliebel yeah. That would make sense because my patch has been applied over 4 years ago now :) That's exactlt the point of the patch

Comment: @sehe Good work! Would you mind updating your answer accordingly? Since it’s possible to specify args now… :)